# Google Forms - Get Item By ID is returning null - Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am trying to pull an item from a Google Form, I believe I have the correct ID's but it keeps returning null.

Here is the snippet of the Google Form that seems to be listing the ID's of the questions:

```
<div jscontroller="yUS4Lc" jsaction="rcuQ6b:rcuQ6b;UxRBlf:rcuQ6b;">
<div jsname="o6bZLc">
<input type="hidden" name="entry.1246438260" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="entry.1940174151" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="entry.1164498160" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="entry.1788372008" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="entry.1406572509" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="entry.1553787825" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="entry.1660954050" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="entry.2017872929" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="entry.844625047" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="entry.176852728" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="entry.1263452961" value="">
</div>
</div>
```

And here is my code:

```
function form (){
var f = FormApp.openById("1q2R07_Ze6M8ltVp_hDH3LMs5iqk6e-2NFad5sS8NAlc");//Google Form ID
var item=f.getItemById(1246438260);//ID of the first Item
Logger.log(item);
}
```

Thank you for your help

Solved Thank you, problem was solved by logging ID's on the editable form rather than the preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

ID being used may be incorrect.

## Solution

You can try getting the list of ids first by using the following code:

```
function form (){
var f = FormApp.openById("1q2R07_Ze6M8ltVp_hDH3LMs5iqk6e-2NFad5sS8NAlc");//Google Form ID
var item=f.getItems();//Get the IDs of all the items in the form.
for(var i in item){
   Logger.log(item[i].getTitle() +" "+ item[i].getId());
}
```

This will return the list of item ids in the form with their respective item title for your reference on the ids.